# Configuring Record Centre Drop Off Library for multiple document uploads

Tags: records-management

The situation is that users will be uploading documents from CD (third party document scanning) with 100 or so documents per CD.

I hope to be able to let the users do one or two multiple document uploads from the CD.
Then they will uses the datasheet view to populate three key metadatafields.

I want to be able to create a Records Centre that will route the documents based on those fields, but my test "Drop Off Library" does not allow multiple document upload.

What configuration do I need to change to allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple document uploads should be possible to the Records Centre drop-off library. Check that you have the Office client installed, you are running a 32-bit version of IE, you accepted the client ActiveX install. Client integration should also be enabled in Central Administration. The client bit might also require Silverlight.

Try creating a 'normal' document library to test you have multiple upload working.

Comment: Cheers, it kinda automagically started working, so not sure what the deal is.